# Chef use different IP Address

Tags: chef

Just moved from Amazon to Joyent (doesn't matter why) and setting up my Chef Server I found following problem:

As you may know, Chef sets the IP address according to the route table. So in my case, the IP informed from the client to the server is my public IP.

I've a recipe to dynamically write the /etc/hosts file, using the IP and FQDN informed from the client. The problem, is that I need to use the private IP so all traffic  reach a local machine will be, in fact, local.

I tried using `node['network']['ipaddress_eth1']` on hosts.erb template file, but is not working.

What cloud I be missing? Is there any other way to write my hosts file using my private IP?

Thanks

**Update**

There's actually a way to find what I'm looking for, using **shef**:

`chef > asdf = node['network']['interfaces']['eth1']['addresses'].keys.select { |a| a[/\A\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+\Z/] }.first`

This will return the IP address on my eth1.

Answer (score -1):

To solve this problem I used the [ipaddr_extensions gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/ipaddr_extensions) and then add **privateipaddress** attribute to ohai.